# How do I use the images I'm undecided between 2 labels in a classification?

Tags: label, classification, data-analysis

I annotated a [dataset](https://zheng-lab.cecs.anu.edu.au/Project/project_reid.html) by direction of person. The labels are `right, left, fore, back`. I can't be sure some of the images if belong the one label.

For example,

Which label should be choosen for the below images? Are these `back` or `right`?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Also, are these `left` or `fore`?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

However, there are images that can be labeled without any doubt.

Such as,

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

You can label above images with a label without any doubt.

How can I handle this problem? Should I exclude uncertain images from dataset or is there method or algorithm to use them to increase accuracy in classification?

Comment: Instead of one-hot, why not give them something like a [0, 0.5, 0, 0.5] encoding, based on which eighth they are facing? Such an encoding would more accurately represent the ground truth of the sample in my opinion, especially since as humans we can't choose between fore-or-left in your example. Not only that, for vision models the predictions will be a lot smoother and more meaningful than forcing them to make arbitrary decisions. What is convenient is that this scheme won't even affect the other, unambiguous one-hot encodings you already have made.

Comment: That is helpfull but I don't think this is the best solution. As you say, this is kinda increasing number of labels so the problem occurs for your solution too. Although `[0, 0.5, 0, 0.5]`  may decrease the loss, some of the persons need to be labeled such as `[0, 0.3, 0, 0.7]`, `[0, 0.6, 0, 0.4]`. However, this is the best solution I have but I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: I doubt that you need precise angle-level encoding like 0.3, 0.7. A model should be able to tell you which two bases the answer is a linear combination of, and not necessarily what the linear combination is. especially if you enforce l1 sparsity on the output layer, it should quickly learn that any answer is a combination of at most 2 of the axes, and softmax will conveniently squish the answers to sum() = 1. however this is just my train of thought, but the only other idea i can think of is increase classes to 8 which is definitely the worse option of the two.